# Is わくわく waku waku a feminine expression?

Tags: expressions, feminine-speech

I tried using this expression but a friend of mine who lives in Japan said it is feminine. I tried searching about this online but couldn't find any indication that it is. Is it really feminine? if it is, how do guys express excitement/elation?

Comment: I'm curious whether the fact that you call it an "expression" means that you used it in a stand-alone way. That would indeed sound a bit childish, and maybe by extension feminine. If you gave your full sentence and explained the situation, it would be a bit easier to assess the femininity.

Answer (score 6):

わくわく is not feminine at all, but a little childish.

楽しい or 楽しみ is a better expression to use in a formal situation.